# How to include US states with zero counts() in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm struggling to craft a query for an Oracle db that will return "0" for each US state that is not represented in the results of this query:

```
SELECT TBL_STATES.STATE_ABBR as State, count(tbl_stations.station_state) AS Observations    
FROM  TBL_STATES 
      LEFT JOIN TBL_STATIONS ON TBL_STATES.STATE_ABBR = TBL_STATIONS.STATION_STATE
      LEFT JOIN TBL_OBSERVATIONS ON TBL_STATIONS.STATION_ID = TBL_OBSERVATIONS.STATION_ID      
WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM TBL_OBSERVATIONS.OBSERVATION_DATE)='2015'
AND   EXTRACT(month FROM TBL_OBSERVATIONS.OBSERVATION_DATE)='8'
GROUP BY STATE_ABBR
ORDER BY STATE_ABBR
```

The query currently returns a count for each state in which an observation has been made, as shown here:

```
STATE | OBSERVATIONS
AZ    | 131
CA    | 30
CO    | 9
FL    | 6
```

...and so on.

What I'd like to see is a count for **every** entry in TBL_STATES (which contains records for all 50 states + DC & PR):

```
STATE | OBSERVATIONS
AK    | 0
AL    | 0
AR    | 0
AZ    | 131
CA    | 30
CO    | 9
CT    | 0
DC    | 0
DE    | 0
FL    | 6
```

...etc.

I've also attempted variations of NVL(count(TBL_STATES.STATE_ABBR),0) without success.

What the heck am I missing here?

Comment: change `WHERE` to `AND` moving the criteria to the join.  The where clause is negating the left join making it an inner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just move the date conditions to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT TBL_STATES.STATE_ABBR as State, count(o.station_id) AS Observations    
FROM TBL_STATES LEFT JOIN
     TBL_STATIONS
     ON TBL_STATES.STATE_ABBR = TBL_STATIONS.STATION_STATE LEFT JOIN
     TBL_OBSERVATIONS
     ON TBL_STATIONS.STATION_ID = TBL_OBSERVATIONS.STATION_ID  AND    
        EXTRACT(year FROM TBL_OBSERVATIONS.OBSERVATION_DATE) = 2015
        EXTRACT(month FROM TBL_OBSERVATIONS.OBSERVATION_DATE) = 8
GROUP BY STATE_ABBR
ORDER BY STATE_ABBR;
```

Because you seem to want to count observations, I also fixed the `COUNT()` to be from the observations table.  This is important when the `left join` does not find a match.

I am a big fan of using table aliases.  Also, direct date comparisons can be more efficient than `extract()`.  So, I would recommend:

```
SELECT st.STATE_ABBR as State, count(o.STATION_ID) AS Observations    
FROM TBL_STATES st LEFT JOIN
     TBL_STATIONS sta
     ON st.STATE_ABBR = sta.STATION_STATE LEFT JOIN
     TBL_OBSERVATIONS o
     ON sta.STATION_ID = o.STATION_ID  AND 
        o.OBSERVATION_DATE >= DATE '2015-08-01' AND
        o.OBSERVATION_DATE < DATE '2015-09-01' 
GROUP BY st.STATE_ABBR
ORDER BY st.STATE_ABBR;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the WHERE clause to AND moving the criteria to the join. The where clause is negating the left join making it an inner.

we may also have to use a sub query to limit the results first then join... or perhaps you need to be counting the occurrences of observation_date instead of station_state, since year isn't in tbl_stations...

```
SELECT TBL_STATES.STATE_ABBR as State, count(b.ovservation_date) AS Observations    
FROM  TBL_STATES 
LEFT JOIN TBL_STATIONS ON TBL_STATES.STATE_ABBR = TBL_STATIONS.STATION_STATE
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM TBL_OBSERVATIONS  
           WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM TBL_OBSERVATIONS.OBSERVATION_DATE)='2015'
            AND EXTRACT(month FROM TBL_OBSERVATIONS.OBSERVATION_DATE)='8') B 
  ON TBL_STATIONS.STATION_ID = B.STATION_ID      
GROUP BY STATE_ABBR
ORDER BY STATE_ABBR
```

Logically the left joins are returning NULL counts for those states... but then the where clause is ELIMINATING the records because there is no observation date thus NULL <> 2015, and the records are being excluded, negating the left join.

Comment: Thanks, but changing WHERE to AND gave me the list for the full multiyear dataset, including zeros where appropriate, but I need the results for a specific month.

Comment: The revised version still returns the the multiyear counts, but many thanks for the help.  Gordon's fix to my count() resolved the issue (along with changing WHERE to AND, as you suggested).

Comment: @Gordan is just that good :P  I didn't change the count as I suggested in text. I've updated it now but still unsure.  Stick with Gordan, he'll take you to good places.